# I would like to auto create an opportunity when a custom field is checked on the account page

Tags: opportunity, process-builder, automation

I tried workflow, but I'm stuck on a formula. 
I've tried a trigger, but stuck again...

can someone tell me step by step where to go and what to do? We are using enterprise addition. They've submitted this request to what I refer to as the Abyss, and it is REALLY hindering my ability to pull reports and jobs.
I would GREATLY appreciate any and all help!

I selected "Conversion Completed" (which is the field I created). When it's true, I want it to immediately create the opportunity. A requirement is close date. I wanted to set the date out 30 days from the creation of the opportunity. I'm stuck in writing the formula.

Comment: you can create opportunity from Process builder. If you face any issues, post with specific question where you are facing issues.

Comment: so I am in Process and I selected "Conversion Completed" (which is the field I created). When it's true, I want it to immediately create the opportunity.  A requirement is close date. I wanted to set the date out 30 days from the creation of the opportunity. I'm stuck in writing the formula..

Comment: check my answer, if the solves then upvote & accept, so that others can find this useful.

Answer (score 1):

To set the Close Date, 30 days from creation date, use

> `Close Date` formula as `TODAY() + 30`

Also, be sure to put the AccountId under which Opportunity is getting created.

Process will look like this:

[image: Opportunity Process]

**Update based on comments**

Name as formula `[Account].Name & '-Conversion'`

`Owner Id`, reference Id and use your user Id

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it through process builder.

Execute process builder when the Account Record updates, and check if that flag is modified.

Answer (score 0):

you can create record on field change in different ways.

- you could use process builder, if there is no complex business logic involved. refer: https://automationchampion.com/2015/02/13/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-1-auto-create-a-record/
- Trigger: you have to create a trigger on Account Object which would create a opportunity record on update.

> ```
> trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before update, after update) {
>    for(Account objAcc = Trigger.New) {
>      if(ObjAcc.Field1 != Trigger.OldMap.get(objAcc.Id).Field1 && ObjAcc.Field1 == True) {  // you can check any condition here
>      Opportunity objOpp = new Opportunity (Name ='demo');
>      insert objOpp;
>     }
>    }
> }
> ```

Reference: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro

If you have specific questions, please post with examples.

Comment: Can you tell me where to go to create that trigger?

Comment: I have updated my answer with link to trail head page. It would help you to learn about triggers.